# Apply WHILE logic on Row-by-Row processing with Cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, cursor, sql-server-2014

I have T-SQL script that is parsing the MDX expression. It looks as:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'tempdb..#metrics' ) IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #metrics

CREATE TABLE #metrics (
Metric VARCHAR(255)
)

---

DECLARE @counter INT = 1

DECLARE @mdx VARCHAR(4000) = 'SELECT {[Measures].[One],[Measures].[Two],[Measures].[Three],[Measures].[Four]} DIMENSION, PROPERTIES OTHER'
DECLARE @startString INT
DECLARE @endString INT
DECLARE @metric VARCHAR(200)

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
       -- loop data and process them
       SET @startString = (SELECT PATINDEX('%[[]Measures%',@mdx))
       SET @endString = (SELECT CHARINDEX(',',@mdx))
       SET @metric = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@mdx, @startString, @endString - @startString))

       IF @metric LIKE '%}%'
          BEGIN
             SET @metric = LEFT(@metric, CHARINDEX('}',@metric) - 1)
             INSERT INTO #metrics ( Metric ) SELECT @metric
             SET @mdx = REPLACE(@mdx, @metric, '')
          END
       ELSE
          BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #metrics ( Metric ) SELECT @metric
             SET @metric = @metric + ','
             SET @mdx = REPLACE(@mdx, @metric, '')
          END

    -- break while
    IF @mdx NOT LIKE '%[[]Measures%,%'
       BEGIN
          BREAK;
       END

END

---

SELECT * FROM #metrics
```

Now, I need to apply this on more rows, but did not figure out how. I tried it with cursor, but it never ends. How to loop the logic on the following rows?

```
DECLARE @srcTable TABLE (
ID INT
,textData VARCHAR(4000)
)

INSERT INTO @srcTable ( ID, textData ) ( 1, 'SELECT {[Measures].[One],[Measures].[Two],[Measures].[Three],[Measures].[Four]} DIMENSION, PROPERTIES OTHER' )
,(2, 'SELECT {[Measures].[Five],[Measures].[Six],[Measures].[Seven]} DIMENSION, PROPERTIES OTHER' )
```

Desired Result:

```
1   [Measures].[One]
1   [Measures].[Two]
1   [Measures].[Three]
1   [Measures].[Four]
2   [Measures].[Five]
2   [Measures].[Six]
2   [Measures].[Seven]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    ID INT,
    Metric VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
    (1, 'SELECT {[Measures].[One],[Measures].[Two],[Measures].[Three],[Measures].[Four]} DIMENSION, PROPERTIES OTHER'),
    (2, 'SELECT {[Measures].[Five],[Measures].[Six],[Measures].[Seven]} DIMENSION, PROPERTIES OTHER') 

SELECT r.ID, item = t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(255)') 
FROM (
    SELECT *, txml = CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(Metric, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML)
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, Metric = SUBSTRING(Metric, CHARINDEX('{',Metric) + 1, CHARINDEX('}',Metric) - CHARINDEX('{',Metric) - 1)
        FROM @t
    ) t
) r
CROSS APPLY txml.nodes('/r') t(c)
```

Output -

```
ID          item
----------- -----------------------
1           [Measures].[One]
1           [Measures].[Two]
1           [Measures].[Three]
1           [Measures].[Four]
2           [Measures].[Five]
2           [Measures].[Six]
2           [Measures].[Seven]
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome, even though the logic is unclear to me yet. Can you please also add version for six columns? I expect my src Table to have 6 columns in total (varchars). Just some dummy data.

Comment: @DNac please check about string split. Aaron Bertrand have a good post about this - http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings